# Question about taylor, formula or already known expansion.

Tags: taylor-expansion

i have just studied the taylor expansion, with the it's formula, which is a serie.

I know that it's formula is:

$\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{f^k(a)}{k!}(x-a)^k$

Where a is the center point.
And the k defines the order of each single term.

Also theres a + $o(x-a)^k$ at the end.

So, with every single function, you can have your expansion that are well known, only centered in zero.

So instead of calculating every time $f^{\text{order}}(a)$ derivates, you can just put the argument in that well-known expansion.

So, for example, we have

$\sin(x)$ and its taylor is:

$\displaystyle x - \frac{x^3}{3!} + \frac{x^5}{5!}$ and so on..

I have two questions:

This is the main one.

> We got:
> $\sin(\frac{π}{x+4})$
> and we have to calculate the taylor (so centered at $0$) with order $2$, i tried replacing (using the well-known) but it is so different than using the formula of taylor.. I don't know which one to use..

This is not really important, I'm just curious about it but didn't find much..

> Why we put the argument in the x when using the well-known taylor? for example: $\sin(3x)$ centered in $0$, we can simply replace the $x$ in the well-known with $3x$. When we do the derivate, with the formula of taylor, the $(x-a) ^k$ is not replaced with our point $a$, but just the function (since it is $f(a)$).

Thank you for your help!

Edit:
I think the answer is: you can apply the well-know expansion only if the argument is $0$, since $π/4$ is never $0$, we have to use the original formula.
Don't know about the second question.

Comment: [Have a look here](https://buraian.medium.com/a-brief-introduction-to-taylor-series-47416e7b9123) it should answer all your questions

Comment: @TrystwithFreedom i have read it all but it didn't answer my first question :/

Answer (score 0):

My apprroach would be to first the Taylor series for $\frac{\pi}{x+4}$ $$=\frac{\pi}{4}\frac{1}{1+\frac{x}{4}}$$ $$=\frac{\pi}{4}(1-\frac{x}{4}+\frac{x^2}{16}-...)$$ For brevity, let's call this expression $ y$, Multiply this expression to find $y^2$ and again to find $y^3$.Then use $\sin y=y- \frac{y^3}{3!}+...$

Comment: So you did the taylor of the argument, and then putting it in the sin's expansion? So the first term is $\frac{π}{4}$ and we stop here, since there is not possible to get the second order?